# How to draw a line parallel to diameter intersecting the circumference of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn a circle and its horizontal and vertical line.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0,0) node [above left] {O} circle (3); % circle of radius 3
  \draw (0,3) node [above] {A} -- (0,-3) node [below] {B}; % vertical diameter
  \draw (-3,0) node [left] {P} -- (3,0) node [right] {Q}; % hotizontal diameter

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now, I want a line parallel to AB passing through (-2,0) and ending on the circumference of the circle at both ends.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Your question doesn't suit its title. The line parallel to AB through (-2,0) doesn't touch the circumference but crosses it. Where you stop to draw it, has no influence on that.

Comment: @Toscho: I guess he meant line *segment*?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 12):

Two different approaches:

## Clipping

You can draw a line longer than required, but clipping it to the circle:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) node [above left] {O} circle (3); % circle of radius 3
  \draw (0,3) node [above] {A} -- (0,-3) node [below] {B}; % vertical diameter
  \draw (-3,0) node [left] {P} -- (3,0) node [right] {Q}; % hotizontal diameter
\clip (0,0) circle (3);
\draw[green] (-2,3) -- (-2,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Clip]

## Calc

You can use trigonometry to calculate the coordinates of the starting and ending points of the line. Using polar coordinates, what you have to find are the angles of those points with respect of the center of the circle. In this case it is easy, since the radius `r` and the `x` distance are known, the angle will be acos(x/r). This calculation can be made in a `let..in` construct.

With this approach you have also the coordinates (in polar form) of the end points of the line, so you can label them also if you need to (as shown in the following example).

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) node [above left] {O} circle (3); % circle of radius 3
  \draw (0,3) node [above] {A} -- (0,-3) node [below] {B}; % vertical diameter
  \draw (-3,0) node [left] {P} -- (3,0) node [right] {Q}; % hotizontal diameter

\draw[red] 
   let \n1 = {acos(2/3)}        % \n1 is the angle
   in (180-\n1:3) node[above left] {A'} -- 
      (180+\n1:3) node[below left] {B'};
   % Polar form uses the syntax (angle:radius)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Calc]

Comment: Accordig to OP, the line should be parallel to AB and go trough (-2,0).

Comment: @Toscho Right! Thanks for noticing it. Updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can avoid the math with the `intersections` library of `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[name path=circle] (0,0) circle (3) node [above left] {$O$};  % circle of radius 3
  \draw (0,3) node [above] {$A$} -- (0,-3) node [below] {$B$}; % vertical diameter
  \draw (-3,0) node [left] {$P$} -- (3,0) node [right] {$Q$}; % horizontal diameter
  \path[name path=transversal] (-2,-3) -- ++(0,6);
  \draw[name intersections={of=circle and transversal,by={Q',P'}}] 
     (P') node[below] {$P'$} -- (Q') node[above] {$Q'$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

This is a pretty flexible approach because the paths can be really anything—circles, lines, Bézier curves, etc.

Comment: Accordig to OP, the line should be parallel to AB and go trough (-2,0)

Comment: Ha!  I think all three answerers read that wrong initially.  Will fix.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Now that only happens very rarely. I should have made a *print screen* of that :)

Comment: I think purcusse's right.  His post was first and had the initial misread.  JLDiaz and I focused on other ways to produce *the same picture* rather than the original post.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Well, in my case I wrote my answer without seeing percusses' one (we wrote them concurrently), so my error was genuine :-)

Answer (score 8):

With a little computation, you can get the angle and then get the symmetrical point.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0,0) node [above left] {O} circle (3); % circle of radius 3
  \draw (0,3) node [above] {A} -- (0,-3) node [below] {B}; % vertical diameter
  \draw (-3,0) node [left] {P} -- (3,0) node [right] {Q}; % hotizontal diameter

\draw ({asin(-2/3)}:3) -- ({-180-asin(-2/3)}:3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Accordig to OP, the line should be parallel to AB and go trough (-2,0)

Comment: @Toscho Haha, nice catch! I think it's my fault that other answers did the same. The correct line then reads `\draw ({180-asin(2/3)}:3) -- ({-180-asin(-2/3)}:3);`.

Comment: Thanks all for the help.. Anyways, I needed to draw lines both ways and by chance got answers for both.. I am new to Latex and the more  I work on it, the more I like it..

Answer (score 4):

Good job for *tkz-euclide*. You have a lot of solutions with **tikz**, the choice depends of what you want to do after this. The solution with *tkz-euclide* is interesting if you want to avoid some calculations, if you want to draw a lot of pictures like this. The only problem comes from my macro `\tkzInterLC` because in some cases the result is not accurate enough.
Interesting too : you can easily adapt the solution for different radius.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzInit[ymin=-4,ymax=4,xmin=-4,xmax=4]
% definitions
 \tkzDefPoints{ 0  / 0 /O, %blank spaces are fine for numbers 
                3  / 0 /P, % but not for the names of nodes
                3  / 0 /Q,
                0  / 3 /A,
                0  /-3 /B,
               -2  / 0 /I}
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal](I,O) \tkzGetPoint{H} % IH perp IO
\tkzInterLC(I,H)(O,A)         \tkzGetPoints{E}{F} % inter circle and line
% drawings
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,3 cm)
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B P,Q)
\tkzDrawSegment[color=red](E,F)
\tkzDrawPoints(E,F)
% labels
\tkzLabelPoints(O,P,Q,A,B,I)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want only a line parallel and through a point, possible is

```
\tkzDefLine[parallel=through I](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{J}
```

[image]

Comment: Remark. I prefer to organize  the code with three parts : definition, drawing, label. I create the macros to be able to do this. Sometimes, the code needs a lot of lines but I think it's more easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

With PSTricks.

### Intersection

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\psset{CurveType=polyline}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={135,0,180}]{O}(3,0){Q}(-3,0){P}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,-90}](0,3){A}(0,-3){B}
    \pnode(-2,0|A){A'}
    \pnode(-2,0|B){B'}
    \pstInterLC[PosAngleA=90,PosAngleB=-90]{A'}{B'}{O}{A}{Q'}{P'}
    \pstCircleOA{O}{A}
    \psline(Q')(P')
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

**Warning:**
I just knew that

```
    \pstInterLC[PosAngle={90,-90}]{A'}{B'}{O}{A}{Q'}{P'}
```

will not work!

### Inverse Trigonometry

As PostScript only provides `sin`, `cos`, and `atan`, we need to define a new RPN operator `acos` as

```
\pstVerb{/acos {dup 2 exp 1 exch sub sqrt exch atan} bind def}
```

The complete code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\pstVerb{/acos {dup 2 exp 1 exch sub sqrt exch atan} bind def}

\psset{CurveType=polyline}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={135,0,180}]{O}(3,0){Q}(-3,0){P}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,-90}](0,3){A}(0,-3){B}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,-90}]
        (!3 -2 3 div acos PtoC){Q'}
        (!3 -2 3 div acos neg PtoC){P'}
    \pstCircleOA{O}{A}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Clipping

Using clipping (for this problem) should be avoided because it makes us difficult to place the `P'` and `Q'` labels (and the dots if needed).

The following example uses node `P'` and `Q'` (used in the second method above) to circumvent the difficulty but it will look so funny because of

```
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,-90},CurveType=none]
        (!3 -2 3 div acos PtoC){Q'}
        (!3 -2 3 div acos neg PtoC){P'
    \psclip{\pstCircleOA{O}{A}}
        \psline([offset=1]Q')([offset=-1]P')
    \endpsclip
```

which can actually be written as

```
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,-90}]
        (!3 -2 3 div acos PtoC){Q'}
        (!3 -2 3 div acos neg PtoC){P'}
```

OK, here is the complete code!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\pstVerb{/acos {dup 2 exp 1 exch sub sqrt exch atan} bind def}

\psset{CurveType=polyline}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={135,0,180}]{O}(3,0){Q}(-3,0){P}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,-90}](0,3){A}(0,-3){B}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,-90},CurveType=none]
        (!3 -2 3 div acos PtoC){Q'}
        (!3 -2 3 div acos neg PtoC){P'}
    \psclip{\pstCircleOA{O}{A}}
        \psline([offset=1]Q')([offset=-1]P')
    \endpsclip
    %\pstCircleOA{O}{A} <-- not needed!
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### The latest edit:

Apparently, `pstricks.pro` has added or defined `Acos` as follows,

```
/Acos {dup dup mul neg 1 add dup 0 lt {% arc cos, returns 0 when negative root
  pop pop 0 }{ sqrt exch atan} ifelse } def
```

so more keystrokes can be reduced.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{CurveType=polyline}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={135,0,180}]{O}(3,0){Q}(-3,0){P}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,-90}](0,3){A}(0,-3){B}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,-90}]
        (!3 -2 3 div Acos PtoC){Q'}
        (!3 -2 3 div Acos neg PtoC){P'}
    \pstCircleOA{O}{A}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```